# Need to make my spawnmanager spawn objects faster with time(Unity c#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, unityscript, 2d-games

Good evening guys, I'm working on this 2D shooter game for a school assignment of mine where basically you have to shoot enemies who move from left side to right side of the screen.

To gradually increase the difficulty I'm trying to increase the interval in which the enemies are spawned, but I can't get my script to work. Here is what i have so far, the void Update part is where I'm trying to increase the speed(without luck), hope someone can give me a pointer :)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {
    public bool SpawnerEnabled;
    public GameObject Enemy;
    public float SpawnInterval;
    void Start () 
    {
        StartCoroutine (SpawnEnemy ()); //starter spawnenemy koden
        SpawnerEnabled = true;
    }
    void Update () 
    {
        public float SpawnInterval+0.001;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

    }

    IEnumerator SpawnEnemy()
    {
        while (true) {
            if(SpawnerEnabled)
            {
            GameObject alien = Instantiate(Enemy) as GameObject;
                alien.name = "Enemy"; //Dette gør at clonen ikke kommer til at hedde enemy(clone) men bare enemy
                alien.transform.position = new Vector3(-20,Random.Range(-4f,5f), 2); // inden for intervallet -4 og +5 på y axen kan objektet spawne, det er dog fastlåst til kordinat -11 på Yaxen og +2 på Zaxen

                yield return new WaitForSeconds(SpawnInterval); // her venter den det antal sekunder vi sætter den til for at spawne næste enemy

            }
                yield return null;
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, but you may need to customize for your use

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {
    public bool SpawnerEnabled;
    public GameObject Enemy;
    public float SpawnInterval;
    private Float timer;
    void Start () 
    {
        SpawnerEnabled = true;
        StartCoroutine (SpawnEnemy ());
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnEnemy()
    {
        while (SpawnerEnabled) {
            timer +=Time.deltaTime();
            if(timer >= SpawnInterval){
              GameObject alien = Instantiate(Enemy) as GameObject;
              alien.name = "Enemy";
              alien.transform.position = new Vector3(-20,Random.Range(-4f,5f), 2);

              yield return new WaitForSeconds(SpawnInterval);
              timer = 0;
              SpawnInterval += Mathf.Sqrt(time);
            }
    }
}
```

Mathf.Sqrt will increase spawninterval like the graph below[image: spawnInterval]

*above image is reference only.*